# std::rethrow_exception compatibility with libc++ and libstdc++?

Tags: c++, linux, exception, libstdc++, libc++

I have a shared library compiled with `--stdlib=libc++` which makes use of `std::rethrow_exception()`.

I need to load and use this library from an executable (`node`) that loads `libstdc++`.

I have found that any exception thrown by my library using `std::rethrow_exception()` did not get caught and crashed the application.

By further investigation I found that I could catch the exception using a `catch(...)` block, but I could not get any information about the exception.

I think the issue might be some sort of ABI compatibility issue between libc++ and libstdc++`.

Here is a small code snippet that reproduces the issue:

```cpp
// libtest.h
void use_rethrow();

// libtest.cc
// compiled using clang++-12 --stdlib=libc++ -shared -fPIC libtest.cc -o libtest.so

#include <stdexcept>

void use_rethrow()
{
    try
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("runtime error");
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        auto eptr = std::current_exception();
        std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
    }
}
```

```cpp
// main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "libtest.h"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        use_rethrow();
    }
    catch(std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "OK: Caught exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "FAIL: Caught something" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ clang++-12 -L. -ltest main.cc
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff25894000)
    libtest.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2b73486000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2b73337000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2b7331c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2b7312a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2b73691000)
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
FAIL: Caught something
```

But if I compile the test application using `--stdlib=libc++`, this works as I'd expect:

```sh
$ clang++-12 -L. -ltest --stdlib=libc++ main.cc
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcf1fc2000)
    libtest.so => not found
    libc++.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so.1 (0x00007f84e64c2000)
    libc++abi.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++abi.so.1 (0x00007f84e648a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f84e633b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f84e6320000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f84e612e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f84e6109000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f84e60fe000)
    libatomic.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatomic.so.1 (0x00007f84e60f4000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f84e65ba000)
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
OK: Caught exception: runtime error
$
$ #but I can get the same unexpected behavior by preloading libstdc++
$ LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
FAIL: Caught something
```

This issue affects `std::promise` and `std::future` as well, since they use `std::rethrow_exception()`.

The question is: how do I catch exceptions thrown using `std::rethrow_exception()` when both libstdc++ and libc++ are runtime loaded?

Comment: _I think the issue might be some sort of ABI compatibility issue between libc++ and libstdc++_ Absolutely, you shouldn't be trying to mix and match them.

Comment: libstdc++'s `std::exception` is a different type to libc++'s `std::exception` so you can't catch one with the other. Don't mix standard libraries

Comment: I understand this is not good practice. I'm building a wrapper for this library, which comes linked to `libc++`, to be used with _node_, which is built on `libstdc++`.
`std::exception` works fine; the issue is with `std::exception_ptr` and the functions that use it.